# nuget content not adding to project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet package that, with a new version, has added items under its content/ directory.

I run `nuget update` against the solution containing the project that is referencing this package. The new files from the package are added, but the project has them excluded by default. As such, each time I add new files to the NuGet package, I have to be sure to manually include them in any project that's using this package.

Is there any way to automate this, like an argument for the `nuget update` command that will force new files to be added to the project?

Comment: Is it related to a specific package?

Comment: It is a package that we frequently use on a local repository of ours, so it's possible that the issue could be the package itself.